# Umbraco Custom Section root View

Tags: c#, angularjs, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm nearly done building my application/section in Umbraco. Everything works out fine with the Angular views and Section-tree routes. BUT i cant figure out where the root view is located.

The other views are located in "App_Plugins/{application_name}/backoffice/{SectionTreeName}"

But what about the view that defines what is displayed when you click on the application logo in the side menu of umbraco? ( Root view )

I havent been able to find any documentation, what so ever!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Aight. I figured it out at last!

What you need to do, is add a new entry to the "/config/Dashboard.config" file, looking like this:

```
  <section alias="SectionAlias">
    <areas>
      <area>SectionName</area>
    </areas>
    <tab caption="Tab">
      <control showOnce="true" addPanel="true" panelCaption="">
        /App_Plugins/viewfolder/backoffice/dashboard.html
      </control>
    </tab>
  </section>
```

Where the section alias, is actually an alias you want to give your dashboard entry in the config-file. The area is the section name / alias you choose when creating the section and the view is the actual view you would like to present.